# How can I logout all users of account kit from system?

Tags: android, laravel, account-kit

I'm using facebook accountkit for my user login / signup. Now I want to logout all the users from my app from back-end,without updating the app in playstore. Is there any way?
I used Laravel in the back-end to generate API and the app platform is Android

Comment: Hi Tamzid, pls refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn how to ask a good question.
In your case I will add some code to show the attempts you already made, it will make easier for the community to understand and help you